# it's possible to skip a Quartz StatefulJob that overlap another one?

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

Scenario:
A StatefulJob A is scheduled to run every 5 minutes on Quartz.
A0 is started at time t0;
t0 = 10 minutes.

In the meanwhile, Quartz try to start A1, but it can't beacause A0 is running.

A0 completed, at time t1 (10 minutes after the start). In this case, Quartz will start delayed A1 job or the new A2?

In this case we can configure Quartz to skip overlapped job istead of delay them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of the misfireInstructionPolicy you have chosen. This typically depends on how you have built your schedule (CronSchedule, SimpleSchedule, etc...).

Have a look at the related documentation:

- [CronScheduleBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
- [SimpleScheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/SimpleScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
- [CalendarIntrervalScheduleBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
- [DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())

PS: links point to the first method of for misfireInstructions but there are several available on each Schedule.

Comment: thanks Guillaume to introduce me in misfireInstructionPolicy!